# Which methods can improve model fit through gradient descent?

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am looking to solve the following question:

Which methods below can improve model fit (MSE) through gradient descent?

- Use a high learning rate
- Use stochastic gradient descent
- Start with a high learning rate, but decrease over time
- Use a different starting point to avoid possible local minima

From my understanding, starting with a higher learning rate but decreasing over time is a good way to balance the problem of overshooting the minimum. I believe using a different starting point can also potentially help the error, as the current model may be stuck on a local minima.

My gut feeling is that the only method that can't improve the error is stochastic gradient descent, as that is technically only considering a subset of the data, so that makes me feel like underfitting is intuitively more likely. Would appreciate any insights!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Updated! Thanks